# How can I make parent class variables Invocable in flow and process builder?

Tags: apex, class, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have a scenario where I have an `InvocableMethod` which takes a custom Class with properties which are made available with the `@InvocableVariable` annotation, but I want this class to extend a parent class so that I can re-use this structure

```java
    public abstract class Animal {
        @InvocableVariable
        public string Legs;
    }

    public class Cat extends Animal {
        @InvocableVariable
        public string Breed;
    }


    @InvocableMethod(Label='Example Method')
    public static void exampleMethod(List<Cat> cats){
        handlerMethod(cats);
    }

    public static void handlerMethod(List<Animal> animals){
        for(Animal animal : animals){
            animal.Legs; // always null and cannot be set in Flow
        }
    }
```

In Flow and Process Builder the Breed property is exposed and available but the Legs property is not.

If I add a Legs property to the Cat class, it does appear in Flow but this does not work either as the object appears to maintain them as separate variables.

How can I ensure that either:

a) the properties on the parent are surfaced in Flow and Process Builder

b) I can pass a value to the parent class for this property

Comment: I have this exact same scenario. Where you able to find a solution?